# Manipulate Spark DataFrame using SQL syntax and save result back to cluster

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, sparkr, sparklyr, rstudio-server

I'm using RStudio Server running on Databricks cluster. One way I use SQL syntax to manipulate DataFrames on the cluster is by using the DBI package. For example,

```
library(DBI)
df <- dbGetQuery(sc, "select * from table_on_cluster")
```

However, this saves the result as a R object (df). I'd like to keep working against the cluster (via sparklyr). Instead of having an extra step to write this back to the cluster, like the below, is there a way I could have done this in one step?

```
tbl_df <- copy_to(sc, df)
```

I.e., I'd like the result of the SQL syntax to be written on the cluster. The above is painful because copy_to is very slow, especially for big data.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is already registered in the cluster, you only need to use `dplyr::tbl` function to create the `tbl_df` object.

```
tbl_df <- tbl(sc,"table_on_cluster")
```

Then you can use `dplyr` interface to manipulate the Spark Data frame.

Here is a full example using `iris` data.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(master = "local")

# Let's suppose iris is your table
sdf_copy_to(sc, iris, name = "table_on_cluster")
src_tbls(sc)

tbl_df <- tbl(sc,"table_on_cluster")

tbl_df %>%
  filter(Species == "versicolor") %>%
  head(3)
```

Result:

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 5]
  Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species   
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>     
1          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
2          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
3          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
```